# R libraries with same names - change the name of a library?

Tags: r, logging

Is it possible to install a r library with a different name in Windows? I am facing a situation: I want to test two loggr libraries hosted in github. Unfortunately they both have same names. Is there any workarounds to install them both without messing the library location, etc.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("erickramer/loggr")
install_github("smbache/loggr")
```

Comment: Have you tried packrat?  https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Comment: or clone from github, change the package name in the `DESCRIPTION` file and build the package. smbache`s package has no dependencies at all at seems to be a perfect candidate for that

Comment: or you play around with the `.libPaths` (e. g. using `with_libpaths`) to install the packages into separate locations and activate only one libpath as required to use one package at a time

Comment: What do you mean with "install them both"? Also using both in parallel (loaded via `library`)?

Comment: I think meddling the 'DESCRIPTION' file seems a better idea for now. It is a hacky solution, looking for a permanent solution. And yeah, I wanted to use them both in parallel if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't the permanent solution to just be one logger after you finish testing them?